# SQL Server 2014: how long the stored procedures waited for lock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2014: I have 2 important stored procedures in my system and 
I am concerned about how long the stored procedures wait for locks.

I am thinking to find a way to determine how long was the lock wait time at the end of the stored procedure, and if it is larger than a certain threshold, create an application log entry and record it.

Is there any practical way (like one of `@@SystemVariables`) to determine the lock wait time so far in a stored procedure without imposing another query overhead into system tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you enable the [`blocked process threshold` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181150.aspx). When enabled it will trigger an event of type [Blocked Process Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191168.aspx) if a process is blocking another process for longer than the configured threshold. This is even better than what you are asking:

- it not only triggers when long waits occur, it also shows you *who* is causing the long waits
- as an event, it can trigger action (eg. send an email). See [Understanding Event Notification](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190427(v=sql.105).aspx)s to understand how to use this event.
- it requires no code changes in your procedures.

Comment: As a side note I'm working to add support for this event with my SQL monitoring service http://DBHistory.com

Comment: Using events is a good idea. However, in the production environment, I do not have access to the server.  I only have DBO access to the database and I can't change that. That is why I have to come up with a design thatI get everything I need within the database. Server level access is not an option for me.

Comment: If you cannot use events, I recommend using [`sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt282433.aspx) which allows you to see the increase of lock wait times in the current session. Requires SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Is there any design that work for SQL14? Hope I am not asking for too much :)

Comment: Ultimately, you are bound to loose this fight. What you're trying to accomplish is monitoring and appropriate permissions are needed. Modifying the code to circumvent this will only result in innadequate solutions.

Comment: You can get timestamp at entry and timestamp at end. Measure the difference, and assume the difference is lock time. But in truth could be anything, IO, CPU.